# Writing to a file using Nginx Lua module

Tags: http, nginx, lua

I'm experimenting with the **[Nginx Lua module](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module)**.  Currently, my goal is simply to save certain HTTP responses to a local file on disk.

After reading a few tutorials, my understanding is that I can do this using the [**`body_filter_by_lua`**](https://github.com/openresty/lua-nginx-module#body_filter_by_lua) directive.  My approach is simply to embed some Lua code in the `nginx.conf` file, retrieve the response body from `ngx.arg`, and then use standard Lua `io` facilities to write it to disk.

I have never programmed in Lua before, but I've programmed extensively in other scripting languages like Python, so I found it fairly easy to learn the basics of Lua.

Still, my approach isn't working, and the nginx `error.log` indicates the problem is that the `file` object I open is `nil`.

Here is the Lua code I place inside the `nginx.conf` file (edited for clarity):

```
   location /foo {
        proxy_pass http://my_upstream_proxy;
        proxy_cache my_cache;
        proxy_redirect default;
        proxy_set_header Host      $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Server $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

        body_filter_by_lua '
            local resp_body = ngx.arg[1]
            ngx.ctx.buffered = (ngx.ctx.buffered or "") .. resp_body
            if ngx.arg[2] then
                ngx.var.resp_body = ngx.ctx.buffered
            end

            local file = io.open("TEST.txt", "w+b")
            file:write(resp_body)
            file:close()
        ';
    }
```

So the idea here is that nginx would simply pass the request on to a proxy, and then write the response body out to a local file.

I test this using:

```
curl http://www.google.com --proxy http://localhost:80
```

But nginx returns an empty reply.

So I check the error log and see:

```
2016/12/15 11:51:00 [error] 10056#0: *1 failed to run body_filter_by_lua*: body_filter_by_lua:9: attempt to index local 'file' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
        body_filter_by_lua:9: in function <body_filter_by_lua:1> while sending to client, client: 127.0.0.1, server: test-server, request: "GET http://www.google.com/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://69.187.22.138:82/", host: "www.google.com"
```

So why is my local `file` variable `nil`?  When I open up a Lua console using bash, I am able to open/create a new local file and write text to it without any issues.

So what am I doing wrong?  At first I thought it might be some permissions issue and nginx is unable to write a file in the current working directory, but it's my understanding that `nginx` runs as root.  I tried an absolute path like `/home/myusername/NGINX.txt`, and it still fails with a `nil` file.  I'm not able to get a more specific error about why `file` is `nil`.

So what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

io.open will return nil if it was unable to open the file. You can retrieve the error message:

```
local file, err = io.open("TEST.txt", "w+b")
if file == nil then
    print("Couldn't open file: " .. err)
else
    file:write(resp_body)
    file:close()
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Permission issue. No right to create/open "test.txt" there. As for me, /usr/local/nginx-1.14.2/sbin/

Solution: grant permission. in my test env., /usr/local/nginx-1.14.2/ `sudo chomd -r 777`

To find what real issue is, try this below, to replace your "io.open" part

```
handle_name, err = io.open(file,"w")
print(err)
```

I got *"permission denied"* error msg with lua statments above.

Answer (score 0):

Not an expert on Lua but in my dabling, I picked up somewhere to wrap **"io.open"** calls in an **"assert"** function. [See docs on assert](http://www.lua.org/pil/8.3.html)

```
local file = assert(io.open("TEST.txt", "w+b"), "Inaccessible file")
```

This will probably just confirm that this is where the code is failing. Looking at that line, I am not sure what the **"b"** mode is in **"w+b"**.

Did you mean to overwrite as in **`io.open("TEST.txt", "w")`** or, append as in **`io.open("TEST.txt", "a")`**?

If you test with these and still get an error, then it means the file is actually not being accessed.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change:

```
local file = io.open("TEST.txt", "w+b")
```

To:

```
local file = io.open("TEST.txt", "a")
```